# Define page layout in geometry similar to Koma Script with DIV 12

Tags: margins, geometry, typearea

I want to define a page layout in geometry that has similar values as that defined by KOMA script. Unfortunately the values that I provide for geometry do not end up in the design as expected.

This is the code that I use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{layouts}

%\KOMAoptions{%
%  DIV=12,% (Size of Text Body, higher values = greater textbody)
%  % DIV=calc % (also areaset/classic/current/default/last) 
%  % -> after setting of spacing necessary!   
%  BCOR=10mm% (binding correction)
%}%
%
%\KOMAoptions{% (most options are for package typearea)
%  twoside=true, % two side layout (alternating margins, standard in books)
%  twocolumn=false, % (true)
%  %
%  headinclude=false,%
%  footinclude=false,%
%  mpinclude=false,%    
%  headsepline=true,%
%  footsepline=false,%
%}%

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
%%% Paper Groesse
   a4paper,
   portrait,
%%% Koerper Groesse
   textwidth=430pt,    % modifies \textwidth, the width of body
   textheight=610pt,   % modifies \textheight, the height of body
   %ignoreall,    % sets both ignoreheadfoot and ignoremp to true
   heightrounded, % This option rounds \textheight to n-times (n: an integer) of \baselineskip
%%% Margin
   inner=4pt,
   outer=22pt,
   twoside,      % switches on twoside mode with left and right margins swapped on verso pages.
   bindingoffset=10mm,  % removes a specified space for binding
%%% Dimensionen
   headheight=17pt,  % Alias:  head
   twoside,
}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\pagestyle{empty}
 \currentpage
 \pagediagram
 \pagevalues
\end{document}
```

For the KOMA script values (geometry commented out) this gives me

[image]

but for geometry, where I try to define exactly these values especially
the margins (even, odd) end up completely different, but also the whole text area is positioned different. I do not expect to have a layout that achieves exactly the same 
page content, but it should be close.

[image]

How do I need to modify the values for geometry to get a similar layout?
And why is it ending up so wrong with the current values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting to much values and geometry warns you:

```
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (430.0pt) is ignored.
```

Remove one of the inner/outer values and calculate the other from \oddsidemargin and bindingoffset:

```
\geometry{%
   a4paper,
   portrait,
   textwidth=418.25555pt,    % modifies \textwidth, the width of body
   textheight=610pt,   % modifies \textheight, the height of body
   heightrounded,
   inner=\dimexpr1in-12.5192pt-10mm\relax,
   twoside,      
   bindingoffset=10mm,  
   headheight=17pt,  % Alias:  head
   twoside,
}
```

Comment: Why did you change the textwidth? I tried your code, but it gives me evenmargin=47, oddmargin=-12.5, whereas I want 22.6 and 3.6. The result is, that the inner space between page border and textbody is  smaller with geometry. Also the textbody start about 1 line above the textbody of typearea. How can I view the result of `\dimexpr1in-12.5192pt-10mm\relax` ?

Comment: I changed the textwidth to get the identical value I got with KOMa (after commenting the `\geometry` command *and* the geometry package). And don't confuse `\oddsidemargin` and "inner margin of odd sides". Look up the geometry documentation. It describes how inner is calculated.

Comment: If I do the same I get 426.79 as posted in the image above (and not 418). I looked up how inner is calculated, but can only find that it has a fixed ration to the outer. Which means that I can not define both manually?. From the pictures it looks like inner=1inch+oddsidemargin. From the code one can find out that the bindingoffset seems to be added to inner.

Comment: The inner/outer problem could be solved with `textwidth=426.8pt` and `inner=\dimexpr1in-10mm+3.6pt\relax`. No the top position is still one line too high.

Comment: With manual tweeking one can set `top = 107.82pt` which is very close to the `\topmargin` of typearea. But I would like to know if this can be calculated from the other values more elegant.